# Problem 1.3 from RCA Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Prove that if $f$ is a real function on a measurable space $X$ such that $\{x : f(x) \geqslant r\}$ is measurable for every rational $r$, then $f$ is measurable.

**Proof:** For every $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}^1$ exists sequence $\{r_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $r_1>r_2>\dots>\alpha$ then $(\alpha,+\infty)=\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}[r_n,+\infty)$ then $$f^{-1}((\alpha,+\infty))=f^{-1}(\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}[r_n,+\infty))=\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}f^{-1}([r_n,+\infty))\in \mathfrak{M}$$
Thus we showed that for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ the set $f^{-1}((\alpha,+\infty))\in \mathfrak{M}$.

We have to show that $f^{-1}((-\infty,\beta))\in \mathfrak{M}$. We can find sequence $\{\alpha_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $\alpha_1<\alpha_2<\dots<\beta$ and $\alpha_n\to \beta$ as $n\to \infty$. Hence $(-\infty,\beta)=\bigcup \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(-\infty, \alpha_n]$ and $$f^{-1}((-\infty,\beta))=f^{-1}(\bigcup \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(-\infty, \alpha_n])=\bigcup \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}f^{-1}((-\infty, \alpha_n])\in \mathfrak{M}$$ since $f^{-1}((-\infty, \alpha_n])=f^{-1}((\alpha_n,+\infty)^c)=(f^{-1}(\alpha_n,+\infty))^c\in \mathfrak{M}$.

Since $(\alpha,\beta)=(\alpha,+\infty)\cap(-\infty,\beta)$ for $\alpha<\beta$. Then $f^{-1}((\alpha,\beta))\in \mathfrak{M}$.

For any open set $U\in (-\infty,+\infty)$ we can represent it as at most countable union of disjoint open intervals $\Rightarrow$ $f^{-1}(U)\in \mathfrak{M}$.

Is my proof right?

Comment: Looks all right to me

Comment: @marwalix, Thanks a lot for you!